# Capistrano: fetch method does not return value at the beginning of deploy.rb

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, laravel, capistrano

I am new to Capistrano.

Basically I want to use client name recieved from the user in the deploy_to path.

```
    set :client, ask('client name','demo')
    fetch :client`
```

Then I set deploy_to as

```
    set :deploy_to, '/php/ca/stg/#{fetch :client}/#{fetch :application}'
    set :shared_directory, '/php/ca/stg/#{fetch :client}/shared'
```

Unfortunatelly fetch does not resolve a value. It stays like #{fetch :client} in the path.

However, it resolves perfectly in tasks. For example:

```
    before :starting, :check_branch do
      run_locally do
        unless execute :git, 'ls-remote --exit-code', fetch(:repo_url), fetch(:branch), { raise_on_non_zero_exit: false }
           fatal "Specified branch or tag #{fetch(:branch)} for client #{fetch(:client)} does not exist in remote repository."
           exit 1
        end
      end
    end
```

I guess I am missing something or I do not understand how this method works. As I said I just started with Capistrano. I am trying to use it to deploy my Laravel applications.

What would be a solution to set dynamic variables using user's input?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically set a variable, you need to use the `-> { ... }` syntax. This defers the evaluation of the code between the brackets until you've collected the user input.

Also, in Ruby to do string interpolation you must use double-quotes, not single-quotes.

So you could write:

```
set :deploy_to, -> { "/php/ca/stg/#{fetch(:client)}/#{fetch(:application)}" }
```

I also added parentheses for clarity (they are optional).

Finally, the more concise syntax for obtaining user input is to simply `ask`. The call to `set` is redundant. In other words, I recommend:

```
ask :client, "demo"
```

This will prompt the user to provide a value for the `:client` variable, with `demo` being the default.

Comment: Thank you Matt. I did not realize that the script gets executed further and it does not wait on "ask". Deffered reference worked just fine.